# How to Change MessageBox Position in C++

Tags: c++

```
void _MessageBox()
{
ResultMB = MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("MB!"), TEXT("Message"), MB_OK);
    if (ResultMB == IDOK)
    {
        for (int q = 1; q < 5; q++)
         {
            ResultMB = MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("hi"), TEXT("Message"), MB_OK);
         }
    }
}
```

I want to make every MessageBox be somewhere else on the screen
But I do not know how to change a position using C ++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MessageBox()` does not allow you to specify a position for its dialog window.  However, you can manipulate the dialog window manually to accomplish this.  It just takes a little extra work to gain access to the dialog window.

Prior to Windows Vista, you can install a thread-local hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) or [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) before calling `MessageBox()`.  The hook will give you access to the dialog window when it is created.  You can then do whatever you want with the dialog window.

For example:

```
// Using SetWindowsHookEx() ...

__thread int MsgBox_X;
__thread int MsgBox_Y;
    
static LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        CBT_CREATEWND *s = (CBT_CREATEWND*) lParam;
        if (s->lpcs->hwndParent == NULL)
        {
            s->lpcs->x = MsgBox_X;
            s->lpcs->y = MsgBox_Y;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
    
int MessageBoxPos(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType, int X, int Y)
{
    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, &CBTProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
    MsgBox_X = X;
    MsgBox_Y = Y;
    int result = MessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
    if (hHook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    return result;
}
```

```
// Using SetWinEventHook() ...

__thread int MsgBox_X;
__thread int MsgBox_Y;
    
static void CALLBACK WinEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    if ((GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_CHILD) == 0) 
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, MsgBox_X, MsgBox_Y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
}
    
int MessageBoxPos(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType, int X, int Y)
{
    HWINEVENTHOOK hHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, NULL, &WinEventProc, GetCurrentProcessId(), GetCurrentThreadId(), WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
    MsgBox_X = X;
    MsgBox_Y = Y;
    int result = MessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
    if (hHook)  UnhookWinEvent(hHook);
    return result;
}
```

On Windows Vista and later, the above techniques will still work, but a better option would be to simply not use `MessageBox()` at all, use [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialogindirect) instead.  You can assign a [callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nc-commctrl-pftaskdialogcallback) to it, and when the callback receives a [`TDN_CREATED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/tdn-created) or [`TDN_DIALOG_CONSTRUCTED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/tdn-dialog-constructed) message, it gives you access to the dialog window, which you can then manipulate however you want.

For example:

```
// Using TaskDialogIndirect() ...

struct TaskDialogData
{
    int X;
    int Y;
};
    
static HRESULT CALLBACK TaskDialogCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LONG_PTR lpRefData)
{
    if (msg == TDN_DIALOG_CONSTRUCTED) // or TDN_CREATED, either one works
    {
        TaskDialogData *data = (TaskDialogData*) lpRefData;
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, data->X, data->Y, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    }
    return S_OK;
}
    
int MessageBoxPos(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType, int X, int Y)
{
    TaskDialogData data;
    data.X = X;
    data.Y = Y;

    TASKDIALOGCONFIG config = {};
    config.cbSize = sizeof(config);
    config.hwndParent = hWnd;
    config.pszWindowTitle = lpCaption;
    config.pszContent = lpText;
    // configure other settings as desired, based on uType...
    config.pfCallback = &TaskDialogCallback;
    config.lpCallbackData = (LONG_PTR) &data;

    int button = 0;
    TaskDialogIndirect(&config, &button, NULL, NULL);
    return button;
}
```

Either way, you can then call `MessageBoxPos()` as needed:

```
void _MessageBox()
{
    ResultMB = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("MB!"), TEXT("Message"), MB_OK, DesiredX, DesiredY);
    if (ResultMB == IDOK)
    {
        for (int q = 1; q < 5; q++)
        {
            ResultMB = MessageBoxPos(NULL, TEXT("hi"), TEXT("Message"), MB_OK, DesiredX, DesiredY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MessageBoxPos is Underfined
E0020 Error ||

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0140 too many arguments in function call ||

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2065 'hwnd': undeclared identifier

Comment: @Progremmer3 the inner `MessageBox()` should have been `MessageBoxPos()` instead. I fixed that. But there is no undeclared `hwnd` identifier in the code I showed.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau 
in the first line Error MessageBoxPos is underFined

Comment: @Progremmer3 Obviously, you need to declare the `MessageBoxPos()` function before you can use it.  I gave you the implementation.

Comment: I know it a Stupid Quest But How i declare the MessageBoxPos()??

Comment: @Progremmer3 If you don't know how to declare and implement custom functions, you need to stop what you are doing and review C++ basics.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
I did not understand what you meant
How i can declere this? please learn me

Comment: @Progremmer3 seriously? Put the implementation of `MessageBoxPos()` above the implementation of `_MessageBox()`. Or, create a new translation unit with its own `.h` and `.c`/`.cpp` files to declare/implement `MessageBoxPos()`, respectively, and then add the `.c`/`.cpp` file to your project and `#include` the `.h` file in other source files as needed.

Comment: Only i need to do is write MessageBoxPos()?? What inside the ()?

Comment: @Progremmer3 this goes back to my earlier comment. You clearly don't understand how to write your own functions, which is an essential skill for any C/C++ developer to have, so stop what you are doing and go refer to a decent C++ book, which covers that topic in detail. That is outside the scope of the question of manipulating a MessageBox dialog.

Comment: I know The basic of C++ But i dont understand.. MessageBoxPos is under found.. i need a libary?? Include what?

Comment: @Progremmer3 No, you do not need a library, `MessageBoxPos()` is a custom function, I gave you two different implementations for it above in my answer, just copy/paste the desired one into your project code. If you are having errors with it not being found, then you are not applying it to your code correctly, or you are not declaring it before calling it. You do know what a function declaration is, don't you?

Comment: @RemyLebeau how is it possible?? MessageBoxPos is not a word saved in my libraries Window.h | Iostream | String .. How can I use something that does not exist ???

Comment: @Progremmer3 <sigh> you are not listening, and I'm getting tired of repeating myself. `MessageBoxPos()` IS A CUSTOM FUNCTION, YOU NEED TO DECLARE AND IMPLEMENT IT IN YOUR OWN CODE. What part of this is not clear to you? Just copy the code I gave you and paste it into your source file about your existing `_MessageBox()` function.

Comment: I'm Sorry.. I'm So stupid .. I understand  Know and this is Work! Thanks you!!Thank you for your patience and forgiveness again if I disturbed you

Comment: @pro: From [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): *"You may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem."* Also: *"Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer"*. Probably best to take the [tour], too.

Comment: WINEVENT_INCONTEXT returned back a null hook. However WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT works. WIN32 API is weird more times.

Comment: There is a problem with your implementation. Namely the version that uses win32 event hook. It might also affect the other version. Upon creating MessageBox() 2 extra windows are created, the button and static control containing the text. The messed up thing is that you receive EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE for these objects as well. And simply calling setwindowpos will cause the button and static control to be moved outside the display area of the message box. A solution is to check the className first. I consistently see on my machine #32770 as the className of the message box.

Comment: A superior solution is to check if the window is a child. If  it is not a child then this is the  actual message box.

Comment: @user13947194 thanks. I'll fix it later when I have more time.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau This is really frustrating. It's not working. When I call messageboxpos in a function no matter what I put for the x and y it just stays in the middle of the screen.

Comment: @AnstonSorensen works fine for me, after incoporating the changes suggested by user13947194.  I have updated my answer to show the code that works for me.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau This is sort of related, but how do you make it so you don't have to close a messagebox for the next one to appear (messagebox appears, 2 seconds later another one appears without any user input)?

Comment: @AnstonSorensen `MessageBox()` and `TaskDialogIndirect()` are modal dialogs, they block the calling thread until the dialog is closed. However, you can use `SetTimer()` beforehand to create a message-based timer and they will dispatch the resulting `WM_TIMER` messages as expected. You can then display your additional dialogs in your timer handler. Stop the timer when the outer-most dialog is closed. In the case of `TaskDialogIndirect()`, you can alternatively enable its `TDF_CALLBACK_TIMER` flag and then handle `TDN_TIMER` messages in your dialog callback function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've been trying to decipher what you're saying and research online, but I haven't been successful (sorry). Can you please provide some sort of example of ```SetTimer()``` and ```WM_TIMER``` working with message boxes?

Comment: @AnstonSorensen There are plenty of examples of using `SetTimer()` if you look around. What you are asking for now is a new question, not related to positioning the dialog, which has now been answered. So please post a new question about the timer issue. Also, you did not make something clear - when a new dialog is shown after a delay, do you want the previous dialog to stay open, or to automatically close? It makes a big difference in how to approach this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To remarks,
The members can be changed directly using

```
((LPCBT_CREATEWND)lParam)->lpcs->
```

And you should only change the position when the hMenu member is NULL
else the text and buttons are placed incorrect.

```
if (((LPCBT_CREATEWND)lParam)->lpcs->hMenu == NULL)
{
    ((LPCBT_CREATEWND)lParam)->lpcs->x = MsgBox_X;
    ((LPCBT_CREATEWND)lParam)->lpcs->y = MsgBox_Y;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest checking `lpcs->hwndParent` instead of `lpcs->hMenu`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that we can change the position of MessageBox. There is no prototype which requests an int value for position and the return value of MessageBox is an int value, which is the ID of the button that you've pressed.

So it's impossible.

But I can propose something.

Create a new window and give a Handle for it such as HWND.

Then change the Windows Position Using SetWindowPos Function:

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd,NULL,PositionX,PositionY,SizeX,SizeY,SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

and for The Beep you can use the MessageBeep() function. It works with the ICON Themes of MessageBox :

```
MessageBeep(MB_OK);
```

or

```
MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

or also

```
MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
```

Comment: @Progremmer3 you need to put it when you handle the create Message of the window , the message is WM_CREATE , after handling it with switch & case statements , you put that line of code , and don't forget to to replace PositionX,PositionY,SizeX,SizeY by the value of your window